# Efficient way of doing forms and charts in sharepoint

Tags: angularjs, angular, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

What is the most efficient way of doing charts/forms on SharePoint?

1. AngularJs web-parts with CRUD Operations.
2. Modifying out of the box forms and adding charts using JavaScript libraries and CSS.

Does one way have significant advantages over the other or does the use case differ?

Answer (score 0):

The most Efficient would be to use third party programs specialized in charts or forms such as [Collabion](http://www.collabion.com/) and [Infowise](http://www.infowisesolutions.com/uf.aspx). It is the easiest way too and can give really beautiful and well built results.

JavaScript and CSS can give decent results but it can be a lot of work to get the expected result.

There is many more third party programs out there to support charts and forms in SP.